# Search nested dicts for key trees

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, python-3.5

I would like to check if a tuple of keys exists in a nested dictionary, similarly to `dict.get`. The functionality can be achieved as follows.

```
nested_dict = {
    'x': 1,
    'a': {
        'b': {
            'c': 2,
            'y': 3
        },
        'z': 4
    }
}

def check(nested, *path):
    for key in path:
        if isinstance(nested, dict) and key in nested:
            nested = nested[key]
        else:
            return False
    return True


check(nested_dict, 'a', 'b', 'c')  # True
check(nested_dict, 'x')  # True
check(nested_dict, 'a', 'b', 'y')  # True
check(nested_dict, 'a', 'z')  # True

check(nested_dict, 'y')  # False
check(nested_dict, 'a', 'y')  # False
check(nested_dict, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'y')  # False
```

Is there a cleaner (or better yet, built-in) method of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python 3.x do `from functools import reduce`.

You can wrap a `try .. except KeyError` (and `TypeError`) and return the appropriate boolean value:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x[y], ["a", "b", "c"], nested_dict)
2
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x[y], ["a", "b", "d"], nested_dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
KeyError: 'd'
```

---

PS: These one lines are sometimes fun to write. But I'd honestly use your version for any production code.